# Problems to integrate Doctrine in Zend3 project

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

After a long time away from Zend, I need to get back into it again. 
My last work on Zend Framework was in 2016. Now I tried to install Zend Framework 3 with doctrine and get stuck.

What I did:

Build the skeleton app with composer

```
composer create-project -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

Did not use the minimal installation and said y on all options. Did update of composer and installed Zend Framework:

```
composer self-update
composer install
```

I started the machine and entered it: `vagrant up && vagrant ssh`

I required doctrine `require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module` and configured it in module.config.php as follow:

```
'doctrine' => [
    'connection' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'driverClass' => PDOMySqlDriver::class,
            'params' => [
                'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
                'user'     => 'root',
                'password' => 'r00t',
                'dbname'   => 'zftest',
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

Then I wrote a controller factory to inject the entity manager:

```
namespace Application\Controller\Factory;

use Application\Entity\User;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Application\Controller\IndexController;

/**
 * This is the factory for IndexController. Its purpose is to instantiate the
 * controller.
 */
class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container,
                             $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        // Instantiate the controller and inject dependencies
        return new IndexController($entityManager);
    }
}
```

Added an entity to the codebase:

```
namespace Application\Entity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="nick")
     */
    protected $nick; 
    ....
}
```

I tried to create the mysql tables via doctrine using this entity:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

The table was not created and I got this error:

> "No Metadata Classes to process."

I tried to test doctrine:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```

and it seems to be working:

```
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.
```

Also tried in the controller to load the tables which I created manually:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

    /**
     * Doctrine entity manager.
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    // Constructor is used to inject dependencies into the service.

    /**
     * IndexController constructor.
     * @param $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $users = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Application\Entity\User')->findAll();
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Which caused following error:

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException
File: /var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:37
Message: The class 'Application\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces 
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php(112): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces('Application\\Ent...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(151): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('Application\\Ent...', Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
#2 /var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(332): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), NULL, false, Array)
#3 /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(78): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('Application\\Ent...')
#4 /var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(216): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('Application\\Ent...')
#5 /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(281): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('Application\\Ent...')
#6 /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php(44): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('Application\\Ent...')
#7 /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(698): Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository(Object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager), 'Application\\Ent...')
#8 /var/www/module/Application/src/Controller/IndexController.php(35): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository('Application\\Ent...')
#9 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(78): Application\Controller\IndexController->indexAction()
#10 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(106): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(138): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#14 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(332): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#17 /var/www/public/index.php(40): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#18 {main}
```

Can someone give me a hint what I am missing?

Comment: Consider your code as a test for loading, nothing else.
@see https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/55

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no definition of where entities should be found.

Here's the link to the missing bit in your code:

[DoctrineORMModule Documentation](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule#entities-settings)

Comment: I thought its always checking all folders? Where do I define that mapping?

Comment: You can set that mapping in your `module.config.php` if you have any, or in your `global.php`.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight your error seems to tell us he can't find 'Application\Entity\User'. 
At start, Doctrine doesn't know anything about your namespaces.
Doctrine uses an AnnotationDriver to get informed about the location of your entities.
So at your step 5, where you specify module.config.php, you will need to add the following code into the mix:

```
<?php
namespace Application;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;

return [
  // ...
  'doctrine' => [
        'driver' => [
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
                'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Entity']
            ],
            'orm_default' => [
                'drivers' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]  
];
```

And offcourse you'll need to setup to paths to your setup.